# How to transform JSON with XSLT?

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT file that is already working with the XML file we have on ActiveMQ. The thing is that we are upgrading the system and we don't have the XML view anymore. Instead we have an URL that return in JSON the queue informations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
            <h2>PROJECT Notification</h2>
            <div style="width:600px;background-color:#e5eecc;border:1px solid #98bf21;margin:10px;">
                <table border="1" style="border-style:dashed">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th width="300px;">Queue Name</th>
                        <th>Queue Size</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="queues" />
                </table>
            </div>
          </body>
       </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="queue">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="./stats/@size" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to know if that's possible to keep using this same XSLT file, just modifying the tags to start reading from the JSON URL instead.

I'm using camel to route to this XSLT, but I didn't want to create a Processor to convert the JSON to XML. Instead I want to use the JSON right away.

Comment: Consider a general purpose language (Python, Java, PHP, C#, Perl, etc.) to parse the JSON into vector/array/list and re-create original XML so XSLT is seamless or directly to HTML.

Answer (score -1):

XSLT operates on XML input, not JSON input.  (While you could parse JSON using XSLT 2.0 string processing facilities, it's still not the right tool for the job.)

Your HTML target is quite simple, so migrating away from XML/XSLT shouldn't be as much of a challenge as it could have otherwise been.  Look into a JavaScript-based templating engine such as [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), [Handlebars.js,](http://handlebarsjs.com/) [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/)...

Comment: What about this link: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json-to-xml-mapping It seems to be possible to use the JSON to convert it to XML inside the XSLT, is that correct?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 3.0, and if so, are you sure you want to take such a circuitous route to populate a simple HTML page?

Comment: Anonymous downvoter, care to explain your discontent?